# How to release object which init it self

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

When writing Objective-C, knowing how memory is managed is important, even with the help of ARC.

Here is a code snippet (non-ARC):

(1)

```
NSAttributedString *tmpAttrbutedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"foo" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Heiti SC" size:13.0f]}];
// how should I release tmpAttributedString here?
tmpAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tmpAttributedString.string attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[NSColor redColor]}];
[tmpAttributedString release];
```

Here is what I currently do to avoid memory leakage:

(2)

```
NSAttributedString *tmpAttrbutedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"foo" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Heiti SC" size:13.0f]}];
NSString *tmpString = tmpAttrbutedString.string;
[tmpAttrbutedString release];

tmpAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tmpString attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[NSColor redColor]}];
[tmpAttributedString release];
```

My questions are:

1. How should I release `tmpAttributedString` in (1), with only one `NSAttributedString` pointer and without temporary `NSString` like in (2)? Is it possible? (The second `init` depends on the first `init`.)
2. What the compiler would do in scenario (1)? I mean how ARC would insert release/autorelease for it? Is there any memory leakage in (1) if ARC is enabled? (Of course explicit call of `release` removed with ARC.)

Thank you!

Comment: alloc and init are only called once in case of any objective C object?

Comment: @dreamBegin Just to make sure. Do you mean I should not reuse NSAttributedString pointer, and should make a new one?

Comment: Shouldn't you just be setting all the attributes on the first NSAttributedString you initialize? There isn't a need to make the second NSAttributedString.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh Sorry, this is not a good example. I know I'm doing some unnecessary job. But assume there is more work done with first attributed string, and then the second alloc init. Thank you.

Comment: @ZhigangAn Are you just wondering what to do in this case in an ARC world? I can answer that if that's your question :)

Comment: @LucasDerraugh Yes, please. And you are welcome to elaborate on how ARC inserts release or autorelease in compile time. Thank you! ;-)

Comment: i was talking about the first example if you allocate memory and initialize it once you can't call alloc and init until and unless the memory is deallocated and the pointer is set to nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for ARC are relatively simple. If you call `alloc`, `new`, or `copy` then ARC understands it needs to call `release` on this object when it goes out of scope. All other objects are assumed to be `autoreleased`. "Going out of scope" means either returning or reassigning a variable. In the case where it sees a reassignment of a variable, it will implicitly put in a `release` call just before it is assigned to something else. If you return a variable, ARC will put an `autorelease` call on that variable so it can last outside the scope of the method; any other existing variables (that aren't autoreleased) that aren't returned but still exist will have an implicit `release` sent to them.

[Apple's official transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) for reference.